# How to rollback plugin's migration in OctoberCMS?

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I has created plugin with one migration. My version.yaml is

```
1.0.1: First version of user
1.0.2:
    - Added new fields to User model
    - alter_table_users_add_contact_fields.php
```

My updates directory contains one migration file `alter_table_users_add_contact_fields.php`.

```
<?php

namespace Mnv\Reminder\Updates;

use Schema;
use October\Rain\Database\Updates\Migration;

class CreateTableNewsRead extends Migration
{
    protected $table = 'mnv_news_read';

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create($this->table, function($table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('news_id');
            $table->foreign('news_id')->references('id')->on('rainlab_blog_posts')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamp('read_at');

            $table->index([
                'news_id',
                'user_id',
            ]);

            $table->index([
                'user_id',
                'news_id',
            ]);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists($this->table);
    }
}
```

I has successfully ran this migration using console command `php artisan october:up`.

But now I want to rollback this migration. As I see there is no informatino about this migration in table `migrations`. So I cant rollback this migration usins command `php artisan migrate:rollback`.

I found that information about plugin version contains in table `system_plugin_versions`. I has manually deleted my table `mnv_news_read` and manually deleted correspond records from `system_plugin_versions` and `system_plugin_history` tables.

```
drop table mnv_news_read;
delete from system_plugin_history where code = 'Mnv.Reminder';
delete from system_plugin_versions where code = 'Mnv.Reminder';
```

After that I tryed to run `php artisan october:up` again. It completed successfully.

My question is how to rollback plugin's migration correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of rolling back migrations is via the [builder plugin](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder) in admin control panel (make sure to install this plugin first if you have not already).

1. Select the builder plugin menu (from top of the page)
2. Select your plugin (by clicking on the arrow '>' button)
3. From left side menu, select `Versions`
4. Select the version you want to rollback
5. Click on the `Rollback version` button

Comment: Is there a way to go about it from the console?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67174062/4793991) @paishin

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/console/commands#plugin-rollback-command), you can run command in console:

```
php artisan plugin:rollback AuthorName.PluginName 1.2.3
```